# eZ Publish template creation

Tags: templates, ezpublish

I'm trying to add a new template (.tpl) file to an existing design for a company. It is fairly basic:
* New page with iFrame that can be controlled from admin.
* Add new CSS to the new file that will either overwrite existing CSS or add to template.

I have tried to find reference to where I should place such a template and how to add it to an existing design, and the only reference I find is how to make a new design. In addition I cannot fully (or at all) understand the catalogue structure.

As I see it I should add a new extension. Anybody have some pointers that are step by step regarding this issue?

Not to mention - is this the right place to ask for this?

Answer (score 1):

You will get a much better traction on the eZ Publish Community Portal, there : http://share.ez.no . Ask your question in the forums : http://share.ez.no/forums

See you there, 
Cheers,

Comment: thanks, I've been there, but have for some reason not asked.... will try - but my impression of the ez forum is that they won't answer this question since it is in direct conflict with selling courses. Hope I'm wrong!:)

Comment: Wroooong ! This is not the way it is :) For two reasons : 1. eZ has other channels to sell, although Community members may need training or an enterprise subscription in the frame of some project   2. The community portal is a free speech place, just like most of OSS online communities. People get help and provide help. Give and take, not everything is necessarily commercial out there ;) Looking forward to seeing you ask your question there ! Cheers !

Comment: Nicolas, what about making share.ez.no compliant with stackexchange network?

Comment: Sounds like an idea. How would you foresee this? We may want to continue the discussion by posting a ticket in the dedicated issue tracker, not to "pollute" this thread: http://jira.ez.no/browse/COM. Thanks Charles-Edouard!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create an object of the class "Link" in your admin. The link url would be the url of your iframe. Then, in your design folder, in override/templates folder, you could create an iframe.tpl file, and tell in override.ini.append.php you want to override the node/view/full.tpl template, normally used to view a node, with your iframe.tpl, only for that Link node you would have created.